# How to apply D3 data interpolate/animate functions to a dynamically changing pie chart

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js, dataset, visualization

I currently have a sample pie chart in the js fiddle that is able to do a static update between two datasets (with the second dataset having more values)

```
[1,2,3,4,5]

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qkHK6/115/

My aim is to get the data join animation depicted in
 http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5682158

There obviously is quite a bit of complication when Mike is using the findPreceding and findNeighbouring functions and these are obviously used to form the animation with the new data.

```
function findNeighborArc(i, data0, data1, key) {
  var d;
  return (d = findPreceding(i, data0, data1, key)) ? {startAngle: d.endAngle, endAngle: d.endAngle}
      : (d = findFollowing(i, data0, data1, key)) ? {startAngle: d.startAngle, endAngle: d.startAngle}
      : null;
}

// Find the element in data0 that joins the highest preceding element in data1.
function findPreceding(i, data0, data1, key) {
  var m = data0.length;
  while (--i >= 0) {
    var k = key(data1[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
      if (key(data0[j]) === k) return data0[j];
    }
  }
}

// Find the element in data0 that joins the lowest following element in data1.
function findFollowing(i, data0, data1, key) {
  var n = data1.length, m = data0.length;
  while (++i < n) {
    var k = key(data1[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
      if (key(data0[j]) === k) return data0[j];
    }
  }
}
```

However I'm really struggling to apply it to my own js fiddle graph I'm unsure how to apply the information  between two simple data arrays as obviously the key functions are not really needed.

If anyone could point me in the right direction or would be able to give some advice I'd appreciate it as I've attempted this several times and I'm still trying to get to grips d3 and its syntax.

Comment: The data joining in the example relies on some data that groups items, which you don't have in your data. Are you looking to do some grouping, or just the animation?

Comment: Just the animation using  two array data sets with one being bigger than the other.

Answer (score 1):

To animate a transition for a pie chart where values are added, the same tween function as with the same number of elements can be used (see e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1346410)). The only difference is the initialisation for the new arcs -- instead from starting from where they actually are, they start from 0 to make it appears as if they're coming in.

The trick is therefore to take this into account when setting `._current`:

```
.each(function(d) {
        this._current = {data: d.data,
                         value: d.value,
                         startAngle: 0,
                         endAngle: 0};
    });
```

Apart from that, the code is basically the same as for the example I've linked to above. Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/qkHK6/123/). I've simplified your code (e.g. removed the additional `g` elements) so that the core update code is easier to understand.